# Data Validation Ignore Blanks of Range populated by Formula

Tags: excel-formula

I have a named range that I'm using to populate a drop-down list. The cells in this range are populated by pulling unique values from another much larger named range on the spreadsheet. When populating this drop-down list, I would like to ignore blank cells in the first named range. I've tried using OFFSET, such as the following:

`=OFFSET(Sheet1!$F:$F,1,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$F:$F)-1,1)`

This isn't working, and I think it's because Excel doesn't consider the cells to actually be blank. The cell is instead filled with a formula and the formula is returning "". Is there any way you guys know of to ignore blank values returned by formulas in drop-down lists?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `=ROWS(F:F)-COUNTBLANK(F:F)` to skip over blank formula results.  The whole formula shoudl be something like:

```
 =OFFSET($E$1,
 COUNTA($E:$E)-(ROWS($E:$E)-COUNTBLANK($E:$E)),
 0,
 ROWS($E:$E)-COUNTBLANK($E:$E))`.
```

Tested:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The formula in the question does not work because `COUNTA` counts **empty** cells, not **blank** cells.

A cell is considered **empty** if it **contains nothing**.

A cell is considered **blank** if:

- it is **empty**
- its value **is an empty string**

If your list starts at the top (or at a known offset from the top) and you want to ignore blank cells after your range, then see the solution below.

But if you may have blank values anywhere in the middle, sadly I don't know a solution for this yet.

The answer from [Michal Rosa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53510676/6219628) did not work for me (using Macos Excel, that might be a reason).

A simplified version works however.

### Solution

```
=LET(r, <YOUR_RANGE>, OFFSET(<THE_FIRST_CELL>, 0,  0, ROWS(r) - COUNTBLANK(r)))
```

Simple example:

```
=LET(r, Sheet1!$F:$F, OFFSET(Sheet1!$F$1, 0,  0, ROWS(r) - COUNTBLANK(r)))
```

Example starting below a header:

```
=LET(r, Sheet1!$F:$F, OFFSET(Sheet1!$F$2, 0,  0, ROWS(r) - COUNTBLANK(r) - 1))
```